# How to fix bpl loading issue in Delphi XE while opening a project?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe, bpl

Very often when I try to open any project in Delphi XE the following issue raises for a few popular bpl-packages:

> Can't load package "Name1.bpl". Component "Name2" can't be registered
>   by package "name1.bpl" because it has already been registered by
>   package "name1.bpl". Do you want to attempt to load this package next
>   time a project is loaded?

[image]

Thanks a lot for help!

P.S. Kill process and double restart of IDE always helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New Delphi have feature of delayed package loading. This should optimize startup speed, when packages aren't loaded, when they are not needed.

This works fine for component packages, but spoils a fun for packages which (for example) modifies IDE menu.

You can tell IDE to always load your package by calling ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable) from Register procedure.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the IDE is not loading another copy of SakEmai15.bpl from a different folder.

Comment: I am sure that IDE is not loading another copy.

Comment: A BPL is just a DLL, and a DLL is reference counted so it can be loaded multiple times from the same path. If the same DLL/BPL is loaded from different paths, they are treated as different instances. Use Process Explorer or File Monitor from SysInternals to verify what the IDE is actually loading.

Comment: We were not suggesting that you are. The IDE can do unexpected things at times. When troubleshooting IDE issues, you should find out what the IDE is *actually* doing, not what you *think* it is doing. Using a Process/File monitor will tell you exactly which DLl/BPLs are loaded and from what paths.